# html slider + javascript slider wont work

Tags: javascript, html

I've made an html + js slider but when I click it, nothing happens. Here's my code:

```js
const accordionItems = document.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-item')

accordionItems.forEach((item) => {
  const accordionHeader = item.querySelector('.value__accordion-header')

  accordionHeader.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const openItem = document.querySelector('.accordion-open')

    toggleItem(item)

    if (openItem && openItem !== item) {
      toggleItem(openItem)
    }
  })
})

const toggleItem = (item) => {
  const accordionContent = item.querySelector('.value__accordion-content')

  if (item.classList.contains('accordion-open')) {
    accordionContent.removeAttribute('style')
    item.classList.remove('accordion-open')
  } else {
    accordionContent.style.header = accordionContent.scrollHeight + 'px'
    item.classList.add('accordion-open')
  }

}
```

```html
<section class="value section" id="value">
  <div class="value__container container grid"></div>
  <div class="value__images">
    <div class="value__orbe"></div>



    <div class="value__content">
      <div class="value__data">
        <span class="section__subtitle">Our Value</span>
        <h2 class="section__title">
          Value We Give To You<span>.</span>
        </h2>
        <p class="value__description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur reprehenderit porro, molestias autem ipsum aperiam
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="value__accordion">
        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bxs-shield-x value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Best interest rates on market
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bxs-x-square value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Prevent unstable prices
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-square value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Best prices on the market
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bx-check-square value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Security of your data
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the position of function `toggleItem`. 
Arrow function is not hoisted. So it has to be called after defined.

```js
const accordionItems = document.querySelectorAll(".value__accordion-item");

const toggleItem = (item) => {
  const accordionContent = item.querySelector(".value__accordion-content");

  if (item.classList.contains("accordion-open")) {
    accordionContent.removeAttribute("style");
    item.classList.remove("accordion-open");
  } else {
    accordionContent.style.header = accordionContent.scrollHeight + "px";
    item.classList.add("accordion-open");
    console.log("class added!", item.classList);
  }
};

accordionItems.forEach((item) => {
  const accordionHeader = item.querySelector(".value__accordion-header");
  accordionHeader.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const openItem = document.querySelector(".accordion-open");
    toggleItem(item);

    if (openItem && openItem !== item) {
      toggleItem(openItem);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<section class="value section" id="value">
  <div class="value__container container grid"></div>
  <div class="value__images">
    <div class="value__orbe"></div>

    <div class="value__content">
      <div class="value__data">
        <span class="section__subtitle">Our Value</span>
        <h2 class="section__title">
          Value We Give To You<span>.</span>
        </h2>
        <p class="value__description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur reprehenderit porro, molestias autem ipsum aperiam
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="value__accordion">
        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bxs-shield-x value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Best interest rates on market
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bxs-x-square value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Prevent unstable prices
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-square value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Best prices on the market
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="value__accordion-item">
          <header class="value__accordion-header">
            <i class='bx bx-check-square value__accordion-icon'></i>
            <h3 class="value__accordion-title">
              Security of your data
            </h3>
            <div class="value__accordion-arrow">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="value__accordion-content">
            <p class="value__accordion-description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus id enim et fugiat at minima facere eveniet magni quas temporibus dicta
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: still not working the slider isnt working